# Why {{ form }} represents a form instance in template file?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

According to [**django official doc**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates),

> All you need to do to get your form into a template is to place the form instance into the template context. So if your form is called form in the context, `{{ form }}` will render its `<label>` and `<input>` elements appropriately.

Where is the form instance named/defined as `form` for template context in django source code? and How can I change the name to something else `{{ my_form }}` for example ?

Comment: A question from my side which will perhaps help you understand (or answer it yourself): "What does context mean in that sentence and how is something passed in the context?"

Comment: Context means the repository of data used for rendering via HTML template files. `How is something passed in the context?` that is exactly what I am looking for !!! Unfortunately, I did not know. I only knew that `get_context_data()` can be used to add extra contexts. Whether those arguments (such as `HttpRequest` instance, Positional / keywords arguments captured from URLs) are by default passed to `view` function ? I did not know either.  Even worse is that I did not see anywhere in Django official document clearly explains above.

Comment: Well the docs don't focus much on that because `form` is a very suitable name for passing a form object into the context. You are correct in that `get_context_data` is used for that purpose. Basically somewhere down the line (MRO) a view may override `get_context_data` to pass suitable values into the context. `view` is passed into the context from the base `get_context_data`, for `request` and `user` those are passed via context processors, kwargs captured from urls are only passed for template views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you aptly say in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072446/why-form-represents-a-form-instance-in-template-file?noredirect=1#comment122079569_69072446):

> Context means the repository of data used for rendering via HTML
> template files.

As to how `form` is passed to the context if you use a function based view, this is completely upto you with what key you pass the form, for example below code will pass it as `my_form`:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'my_form': my_form})
```

In case of a class based view most of them inherit from `ContextMixin` which declares the method `get_context_data` that is used to pass variables into the context. All class based views that deal with forms also inherit from `FormMixin`, looking at its [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3921b1c6d24c9d5a60e5f5f83c9a394104089c21/django/views/generic/edit.py#L63-L67) it overrides `get_context_data` to pass the form into the context:

> ```py
> def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>     """Insert the form into the context dict."""
>     if 'form' not in kwargs:
>         kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
>     return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
> ```

Of course you can decide to again override `get_context_data` yourself and pass the form with some other name, but doing so wouldn't be very useful:

```
class YourView(CreateView):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['my_form'] = context['form']
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.  After few days frustration on this issue and its related ones, your answer finally brought me to the "aha moment".

Answer (score 2):

When rendering your view in Views.py you can do the following to change the name of the form that you render:

Views.py

```
from .forms import MyForm1

def MyForm(request):
    my_form = Myform1
    return render(request , 'MyForm.html' , {'my_form' : my_form})
```

Then when calling your form on the HTML page you can call it as

```
{{ my_form }}
```